# Where is the "Display file name" option for a LAS dataset in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, labeling, las, lasd

In ArcMap, I can easily label the file name for a LAS dataset through the layer properties.

[image]

In ArcGIS Pro I can only see limited options.

Is there any way of labeling the file name?

[image]

Comment: If the file name is important to you, may be you should head over to [ESRI ideas website](https://community.esri.com/t5/custom/page/page-id/arcgis-ideas) and suggest the idea to include it in a future version, you could link to this discussion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe ArcGIS Pro is exposing the LAS file name property as in ArcMap, but you can display the extent:

[image: Setting file extent on LAS file]